# How to find a reason for a change in Ubuntu? (example: removal of package wslu from the default installation)

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, 22.04, development, default-programs, release-management

I would like to check the decision process for a certain change in Ubuntu. I found the commits implementing the change but in the changelog there is just a plain statement of the change without any explanation or reasoning. I am not able to find any references to a discussion or explanation.

**This question is not about the specific change** which is shown mainly as an example and to illustrate what I have already tried.

### What I have tried (+ specific details)

In older Ubuntu versions the package `wslu`<sup>[1](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/wslu)</sup> was installed by default on Ubuntu for WSL. Since 22.04 it is not being installed any more.

The package used to be installed as a dependency of `ubuntu-wsl`<sup>[2](https://packages.ubuntu.com/jammy/ubuntu-wsl)</sup> which is created from the source package `ubuntu-meta`<sup>[3](https://packages.ubuntu.com/source/jammy/ubuntu-meta),[4](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubuntu-meta)</sup>

The dependency was removed from `ubuntu-wsl` for the target `amd64` in the commit [c846724c7d249e0ff6d3a38a6a91468794e910eb](https://git.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubuntu-meta/commit/?h=ubuntu/jammy&id=c846724c7d249e0ff6d3a38a6a91468794e910eb) with only this message:

```
* Removed wslu from wsl [amd64 arm64]
```

I tried to look for the reason of the removal at these places:

- https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubuntu-meta
- https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubuntu-meta
- https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/wslu
- https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-devel-discuss/ (manually, no reasonable search interface found)
- https://ubuntuforums.org/

I have not found anything.

### Questions

Did I miss something? Are such changes usually made without a discussion and writing down reasons? If they are discussed what is the usual platform for the discussion? What is the best procedure to question this change?

Comment: Given that AskUbuntu consists primarily of volunteers rather than employees from Canonical, it’s unlikely that you will receive an answer 

Comment: @matigo The question is **not** about the specific change. I hope that my edit made it clearer. I hope that on AskUbuntu there are multiple users who know the development processes of Ubuntu. AFAIK Ubuntu is not being developed only by Ubuntu employees.

Comment: *"I would like to check the decision process for a certain change in Ubuntu"* - is your very first sentence... So what is it you're asking? If you're asking how Ubuntu is developed that is extremely broad and not a good question for our Q&A format. See: https://askubuntu.com/help/dont-ask Most of the software in Ubuntu repos is not even developed by Ubuntu contributors. A great deal comes from Debian, and even those aren't developed by Debian contributors, but the open source community at large. As you can imagine, there's a LOT of variance in development practices of individual applications.

Comment: If you're only asking about this particular change, that would definitely be on-topic. Hopefully someone will be able to find some kind of discussion or communication from the developers of this software that would explain the change, but that kind of information is not always published. Commit messages are usually good sources for this kind of info, but you've already seen that. This may be helpful reading: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Upstream

Comment: @Nmath *"I would like to check the decision process for a certain change in Ubuntu"* - this sentence is just explaining what I am trying to achieve, not (primarily) what I am asking here. I am asking how to get the information. --- Of course I would be glad if I get the information about the specific change as an additional reply :) --- I am not asking "How is Ubuntu developed in general." I think I have a pretty good idea about that. Please notice that *I have linked the commit.* --- **I am asking where are the Ubuntu (not upstream) changes discussed and how can I question them.**

Comment: I think you'll just have to accept that some discussions, especially those involving closed-source stuff like WSL (not the kernel or the distro, but all the other Windows components involved which are developed [cathedral style](https://www.catb.org/~esr/writings/cathedral-bazaar/)) will be at least partially, if not fully, done in channels not open to the public. This will in turn mean even open source components will be affected by these closed discussions.